# Firebase Auth not working in Flutter

Tags: firebase, google-signin, flutter

Somehow Firebase Authentication doesn't work in my Implementation. I implemented Google SignIn with Firebase Authentication following the [Firebase Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0), but changed the `ensureLoggedIn` function to:

```
Future<Null> _ensureLoggedIn() async {
  GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
  print('SIGNIN');
  if (user == null) user = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  if (user == null) {
    user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    print('LOGIN');
  }
  if (auth.currentUser == null) {
    GoogleSignInAuthentication credentials =
        await googleSignIn.currentUser.authentication;
    await auth.signInWithGoogle(
      idToken: credentials.idToken,
      accessToken: credentials.accessToken,
    );
    print('CURRENTUSER');
  }
}
```

where I used the console outputs to verify which parts of the function are executed. The function call happens every time the app is started, by calling it in the `main()` function as

```
main() async{
     new LinearProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,);
     await _ensureLoggedIn();
     runApp(new SpringsterApp());
 }
```

I noticed however that although the Signin prompt with the available Google Accounts on the device happens every time the user has not signed in yet, the last part of the `ensureLoggedIn` function (`if (auth.currentUser == null)`) never gets executed, regardless of whether or not the user is signed in.

I noticed this since the `print('CURRENTUSER');` is never put out in the console, and additionaly because no new user is created in the Firebase Auth console. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I could maybe fix this?

My Firestore security rules are set to auth only, so no data can be written or read as long as this error occurs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure all packages are the latest. Run `flutter clean` and see if that works

Comment: @Viv Sadly `flutter clean` didn't work, and I use all the latest versions of cloud_firestore, google_sign_in and firebase_auth in the project. Maybe my implementation in the `main()` function with `async` is wrong?

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions in this page https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth#pub-pkg-tab-installing . I had the same issue before and the reason was because the platform code for google sign in was not found.

Comment: I followed the installation instructions, and the Google Sign-In dialog with the available Google accounts also does pop up. This is why I would expect some parts of my implementation to be wrong, since the Firebase Console does not show a new user and additionaly the Firestore plugin does not allow any reads and writes if set to auth only (although I selected a Google account in my test app). Did the Google Sign-In dialogue also appear when you had the problem?

Comment: @Viven Solved it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To anyone interested, I was able to sign in as planned with:

```
Future<Null> _ensureLoggedIn() async {
  GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
  if (user == null) user = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  if (user == null) {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;
    final FirebaseUser user = await auth.signInWithGoogle(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you define 'auth'?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt reply earlier. 'auth' is defined as 'final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;' above the snippet I copied, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

i already initilized firebase app. But still not connect to firebase auth. So i follow from pub dev docs [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/example).

ran on emulator.

```
bool shouldUseFirebaseEmulator = false; // before main()

if (shouldUseFirebaseEmulator) {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
} // inside main()
```